# Evento em uma única div com classes iguais. Como fazer?

Tags: html, jquery, div

Saudações.
Criei algumas div dentro de um foreach, todas com a mesma classe, dentro dessa div tem um elemento que desejo, ao ser clicado, mostre uma outra div que esta dentro da div pai criada. Porém, como era de se esperar, quando aciono tal evento, são mostradas todas as sub-divs de todas as divs criadas.

Para exemplificar, segue um codigo que replica o que estou fazendo:

HTML:

```
<div class='pai'> 
   <i class='elementoDisparo'>
   <div class="divQueAparece">
</div>

<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>
    <div class="divQueAparece">
</div>

 <div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>
    <div class="divQueAparece">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  $(".divQueAparece").hide();
  $(".elementoDisparo").click(function(){
     $(".divQueAparece").toggle(300);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa achar apenas a `div` que está na mesma `div` pai. Da forma que está fazendo, está aplicando o `.toogle` a todas com classe `.divQueAparece`. Pode fazer da forma abaixo:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  $(".divQueAparece").hide();
  $(".elementoDisparo").click(function(){
     $(this)
     .closest(".pai")
     .find(".divQueAparece")
     .toggle(300);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>clique-me1</i>
    <div class="divQueAparece">div filho 1</div>
</div>

<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>clique-me2</i>
    <div class="divQueAparece">div filho 2</div>
</div>

<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>clique-me3</i>
    <div class="divQueAparece">div filho 3</div>
</div>
```

---

**Se quiser que uma se feche após abrir outra**, basta adicionar:

```
$(".divQueAparece:visible")
.not($this)
.toggle(300);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  $(".divQueAparece").hide();
  $(".elementoDisparo").click(function(){

     var $this = $(this).closest(".pai").find(".divQueAparece");

     $(this)
     .closest(".pai")
     .find(".divQueAparece")
     .toggle(300);

     $(".divQueAparece:visible")
     .not($this)
     .toggle(300);
     
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>clique-me1</i>
    <div class="divQueAparece">div filho 1</div>
</div>

<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>clique-me2</i>
    <div class="divQueAparece">div filho 2</div>
</div>

<div class='pai'>
    <i icon dropdown class='elementoDisparo'>clique-me3</i>
    <div class="divQueAparece">div filho 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: UAU!!! Muito bom!!!